# ReactJS navigation from service

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

In a ReactJS app I want to navigate to another route from a service.

I tried [this approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-boilerplate-ftctmg) trough an external history with `createBrowserHistory` but it would just change the url without updating the route.

I think I'm stuck through outdated info about mixed versions of both React and the router, anyone can tell me the current way to do that?

TIA

Comment: This is a valid way to navigate. Are you making sure to call createBrowserHistory only once and calling history.push on the very same object that you pass to the Router prop?

Comment: I did modify on the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-boilerplate-ftctmg?file=History.js) the history file, no luck tho. It's probably something pretty obvious :(

Comment: You need to import BrowserRouter: import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the version of the *history* npm library, as the latest one is compatible with react router **v6** (which is still in beta). Downgrading to a previous version worked fine ( **npm i history@4.10.1** ).